# Ambiguous use of 'continue' Bolts-Swift in swift 3

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift3, bolts-framework

I'm trying to use bolts in my project.

I'm getting this error when I Try to use bolts with continue.

```
Ambiguous use of 'continue'
```

also this is my code.

```
return PFUser._privateDigitsLoginWithConfiguration(configuration: configuration).continue{ task in
            guard let result = task.result as? [String:AnyObject] else {
                return nil
            }
            let requestURLString = result[Constants.requestURLStringKey] as! String
            let authorizationHeader = result[Constants.authorizationHeaderKey] as! String
            print(Constants)
            return PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "loginWithDigits", withParameters: ["requestURL": requestURLString, "authHeader": authorizationHeader])
            }.continue {
                PFUser.become(inBackground: $0.result as! String)
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Does it help if you put parentheses around the continue blocks? That is, you now use

```
.continue ({ })
```

instead of

```
.continue { }
```

I had the same problem and after Googling found multiple mentions of this and it helped me. It seems like that became a requirement on a recent Swift version change.

This would be your code with the parentheses:

```
return PFUser._privateDigitsLoginWithConfiguration(configuration: configuration).continue ({ task in
            guard let result = task.result as? [String:AnyObject] else {
                return nil
            }
            let requestURLString = result[Constants.requestURLStringKey] as! String
            let authorizationHeader = result[Constants.authorizationHeaderKey] as! String
            print(Constants)
            return PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "loginWithDigits", withParameters: ["requestURL": requestURLString, "authHeader": authorizationHeader])
            }).continue ({
                PFUser.become(inBackground: $0.result as! String)
        })
```